# Does ${O}2^n$ grow faster or slower than ${O}3^{(n/2)}$?

Tags: asymptotics

Is $\mathcal{O}(3^{n/2})$ equal to $\mathcal{O}(3^n)$? I am not sure how the growth of exponentials with fractions.

Comment: MathJax hint:  enclose multicharacter exponents in braces, so 3^{(n/2)} will give $3^{(n/2)}$.  The stuff in braces gets treated as a unit.  It works for fractions, subscripts, etc.

Comment: Ok, trying to edit on my phone, thanks

Comment: Your title and body ask slightly different questions: do you mean $2^n$ or $3^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $a^{b\cdot c}=(a^b)^c$. So e.g. $3^{n\over 2}=3^{n\cdot{1\over 2}}=(3^{1\over 2})^n$.

Now if $0<u<v$, what do you know about the growth rates of $u^n$ versus $v^n$?

Comment: So this means if simplified, it would be O 2^n = O 1.7^n? So 2 grows slower than 3^1/2?

Comment: @BloopieBloops I don't understand that comment at all. How are you assuming $\mathcal{O}(2^n)=\mathcal{O}(1.7^n)$? And what do you mean by "$2$ grows slower than $3^{1\over 2}$"?

Comment: I meant i can say that 3^(n/2) = O (2^n) right? Or 2^n = Ω (3^(n/2))